# arraylist<string> error in android class

Tags: android

i have problem in using arraylist in my class infolisttask ,in this class it loads some data into usrarraylist and i use Log.i two times first time out of infolisttask class it gives me some error that its size is 0 , but when i use Log.i in second class it works correctly , I want to it works in first time to and always have that arraylist , what should i do ?

```
 public class Signin extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> usrArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
    String feedUrl= "http://107.170.117.18:7000/infoes/";
    Context context;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.signin);
      context=this;

      infoListTask loaderTask = new infoListTask();
      loaderTask.execute();

      1_Log.i("yes", loaderTask.usrArrayList.get(2).toString());

     }

     public class infoListTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

            ProgressDialog dialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog= new ProgressDialog(context);
                dialog.setTitle("Loading ...");
                dialog.show();

                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(feedUrl);
                    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    String jsonData = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    Log.i("You json Data", jsonData);

                    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonData);

                    for (int i=0; i<json.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject user  = json.getJSONObject(i);
                        usrArrayList.add(user.getString("username"));
                    }               


                    2_Log.i("yes", usrArrayList.get(2).toString());


                catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                     //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                //videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }


        }


}
```

can I using this code in onPostExecute?

```
final EditText usr= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
              final int x = usrArrayList.size();
              menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        for (int i=0 ; i<x ; i++)
                        {
                            if(usr.getText().toString()==usrArrayList.get(i).toString())
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this,Fragment1.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you familiar with threads? The infoListTask is executed asynchronously and thus the 1_Log.i(...) in your onCreate() function is executed prior to the REST call populating the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will give you exception at first time because you are trying to access data when your User arraylist is null.

**Error at:**

```
1_Log.i("yes", loaderTask.usrArrayList.get(2).toString());
```

**Reason:**

Task isn't completed during that time so usrArrayList will be empty. FYI, usrArrayList will be having data only after the successful response from your webAPI, for which you have written code inside `doInBackground()`.

But if you want to access data after the completion of AsyncTask execution, then write those code inside `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first `log.i` gives exception because your arraylist is empty. At first time.And you are using `AsyncTask` to fill `arraylist` from Json.
So use Arraylist in `onPostExecute` method.After `AsyncTask` has completed its task.As

```
 @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                //videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("yes", usrArrayList.get(2).toString());
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will give you exception at first time. Because the task is not completed then